# SQL does not equal 0.00 decimal value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a SQL call that avoids orders with Subtotal of $0. I can't get it to omit orders that have a Subtotal of 0.00.

My SQL call:

```
SELECT Orders_Products.productID, 
       Orders_Products.QtyOrdered,
       Orders.DateCreated, 
       Orders_Products.Subtotal, 
       SUM(Orders_Products.Subtotal) as Revenue 
FROM `Orders_Products` 
INNER JOIN Orders 
ON Orders_Products.OrderID = Orders.OrderID 
WHERE ProductID <= 21 
    AND ProductID >= 19 
    OR ProductID = 41 
    AND Orders_Products.Subtotal <> 0.00 
    AND MONTH(Orders.DateCreated) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
    AND Year(Orders.DateCreated) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY DateCreated 
ORDER BY `Orders`.`DateCreated` DESC
```

This is where I'm having the issue (still shows orders with Subtotal 0.00):

```
AND Orders_Products.Subtotal <> 0.00
```

I've also tried

```
AND Orders_Products.Subtotal != 0.00
AND Orders_Products.Subtotal <> 0
AND Orders_Products.Subtotal <> "0.00"
```

But my output still includes line items with Subtotal 0.00:

[image]

Comment: What is type of Orders_Products.Subtotal column?

Comment: 2 things - having is the clause to use for a where clause on an aggregate.  having sum(subtotal) <> 0.   Second - this query will fail on any database but MySQL...you need to group by all columns in the select clause that are not aggregates.  MySQL likes doing the wrong thing instead...odds are this query isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: and a third thing...the and/or evaluation in your where clause might not be functioning as you think it is.  Use brackets to group the and/or's correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is something wrong with brackets.
It looks like it should be gathered as one condition:

```
(ProductID <= 21 AND ProductID >= 19 OR ProductID = 41)
```

Comment: You're right that it's an issue, but it's not the answer to his question

Comment: @Twelfth Why it is not answer? Following her sql query in question result with productId=21 and Subtotal = 0.00 is correct. So there is problem in condition sequence.

Comment: There's a difference between subtotal <> 0 and sum(subtotal) <> 0...it'll omit the single line that has the subtotal <> 0, but the sum(subtotal) <> 0 is still there.  No way the group by is doing as she intends either.